# Escaping question mark in AWK

Tags: regex, awk, escaping

I want to do something as simple as:

```
myregex = "A\?B"
```

or

```
  if (match($O, "A\?B")) print "YES"
  else print "NO"
```

In the first example, I am getting this:

```
warning: escape sequence '\?' treated as plain '?'
```

In the second example, it simply doesn't match the corresponding lines.

I am using GAWK 3.1.6 on Windows - got it from gnuwin32 package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String constants (such as `"A\?B"`) are [scanned twice](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Computed-Regexps.html#Computed-Regexps):

> the first time when awk reads your program, and the second time when
>   it goes to match the string on the lefthand side of the operator with
>   the pattern on the right.

The first slash is eaten by the first scan, so you need to escape the backslash with another backslash, i.e. `"A\\?B"`:

```
if (match($0, "A\\?B")) print "YES"; else print "NO";
```

However, as it is said in [the docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Computed-Regexps.html#index-string-constants_002c-vs_002e-regexp-constants), it is usually better to use *regexp constants*:

```
if (match($0, /A\?B/)) print "YES"; else print "NO";
```